# Why does my key signing fail?

Tags: android

I can't sign my app in order to put it in the Play Store.

When I try to create a new signing key I get the following message : "Passwords cannot contain quote character"

Obviously, I do not have any quote characters in my new password.  All my fields are filled. I even limited my password to upper and lower case letters as well as numbers, and it still fails.

I googled it, but didn't find anything... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in the key management gui.  I used keytool from the command line and it took my key without a problem.